# mpl.gca(), close() leaks memory

Tags: matplotlib, memory-leaks

I noticed that the memory consumption of a long-running program increases to the point where it crashes. I've boiled it down to

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    plt.gca()
    plt.close()
```

Let it run, and watch the memory consumption of the process increase. This is with matplotlib 3.5.3.

What's the reason for this?

Comment: see also https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22448